# PHP regex check if string not contain string then replace

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have a long string that contain many img tags (PHP):

```
$content = '<img src="url" class="img lazy"/><div class="wrap"><img src="url" class="img" /></div><img src="url" class="lazy" />';`
```

How to use regex to check in string: if  not contain class "lazy" then change src to data-src?

In this case the output is:

```
<img src="url" class="img lazy"/><div class="wrap"><img data-src="url" class="img" /></div><img src="url" class="lazy" />
```

Comment: i think you're better off using an HTML parser instead, check out `DOMDocument`

Comment: if (preg_match('/class="lazy"/',$content)) can check if you have a class=lazy in the string. But it's not what I'd recommend.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\<img )src(?=.+?lazy\"\>)/g', "data-src", $content);
```

Comment: Thanks for help but it not work